# lucene Fields vs. DocValues

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm using and playing with Lucene to index our data and I've come across some strange behaviors concerning DocValues Fields.

So, Could anyone please just explain the difference between a regular Document field (like **StringField**, **TextField**, **IntField** etc.) and DocValues fields
(like **IntDocValuesField**, **SortedDocValuesField** (the types seem to have change in Lucene 5.0) etc.) ?

First, why can't I access DocValues using **document.get(fieldname)**? if so, how can I access them?

Second, I've seen that in Lucene 5.0 some features are changed, for example sorting can only be done on DocValues... why is that?

Third, DocValues can be updated but regular fields cannot (you have to delete and add the whole document)...

Also, and perhaps most important, when should I use DocValues and when regular fields?

Joseph

Answer (score 12):

Most of these questions are quickly answered by either referring to the Solr Wiki or to a web search, but to get the gist of DocValues: they're useful for all the other stuff associated with a modern Search service except for the actual searching. From the  [Solr Community Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues):

> DocValues are a way of recording field values internally that is more efficient for some purposes, such as sorting and faceting, than traditional indexing.
>
> ...
>
> DocValue fields are now column-oriented fields with a document-to-value mapping built at index time. This approach promises to relieve some of the memory requirements of the fieldCache and make lookups for faceting, sorting, and grouping much faster.

This should also answer why Lucene 5 requires DocValues for sorting - it's a lot more efficient than the previous approach.

The reason for this is that [the storage format is turned around](https://lucidworks.com/post/fun-with-docvalues-in-solr-4-2/) from the standard format when gathering data for these operations, where the application previously have to go through each document to find the values, it can now look up the values and find the corresponding documents instead. Which is very useful when you already have a list of documents that you need to perform an intersection on.

If I remember correctly, updating a DocValue-based field involves yanking the document out from the previous token list, and then re-inserting it into the new location, compared to the previous approach where it would change loads of dependencies (and reindexing was the only viable strategy).

Use DocValues for fields that need any of the properties mentioned above, such as sorting / faceting / etc.

Comment: thanks, but this does'nt really answer the question.

I know that they are more efficient in sorting... but it does not explain the strange behavior.
how do I retrieve their value from the document? document.get(fieldname) does not seem to work, what good is it If I cannot access it?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein It answers most of your questions - Is your field stored? Only stored fields will return a value; docValues is an indexing strategy and shouldn't affect retrievability. Include a minimal example of the issue if you have actual code you're trying to get to work.

Comment: I've run into issues with understanding when and when not to use DocValues too, and Apache Solr's documentation in general. It's annoying for someone to state that most of these questions are _quickly_ answered by referring to the SolrWiki or a web search. Are you saying that because you don't think the poster did their due diligence before asking, or because you think it's a useful fact to know? If it's the former, it's insulting to say the least, and trust me, for many people, that's the reason why they _do_ read the documentation before turning to stackoverflow.

Comment: If it's the latter, don't waste your time. Everyone knows that Apache Solr has documentation, and if it made the solution obvious, I'm sure the op wouldn't have asked in the first place. I've been reading over Solr's documentation over the last week, page-by-page; literally doing nothing else but eating and getting 8hrs, and I'm not surprised when I see people saying that the documentation for Solr is of low quality or that there is some initial learning phase that's tough to get over; especially when it's being compared to Sphinx or ElasticSearch.

Comment: I think that if instead of citing the SolrWiki every time somebody asks a question about Solr, the developers took that time to think about how the documentation may be flawed, I wouldn't be looking at this post over a year later with very similar issues.

Comment: @thebeest Sure! Nothing would be better! In that case the important part is that the _question_ conveys what they asker has trouble understanding about the concept and the documentation, so that anyone answering the question knows where they're coming from (and that they just haven't read the multitude of resources already attempting to explain or document a similar issue). Assuming that all users has read and understood all the documentation related to their problem before asking would mean that all questions could be assumed esoteric.

Comment: What helped me better understand this is the blog article here: https://sease.io/2020/03/docvalues-vs-stored-fields-apache-solr-features-and-performance-smackdown.html.