# FieldvalueCache not bein populated in solr 6.3 even though we are faceting on several fields?

Tags: caching, solr, lucene

We have large index of 200 GB. We have query requirements where we perform faceting on 5-6 fileds (whitespace tokenized). I have read solr documents which says Faceting tokenized field will populate fieldvalueCache. But for some reason all the facets are cached in FieldCache rather than fieldvaluecahe. Can someone explain as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to Solr favors docValue to fieldValueCache.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5666

if you want to use fieldValueCache, you can do via json facet.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8466

here is some more discussion regarding the changes

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7190

Here is some related discussion in stackoverflow,

[lucene Fields vs. DocValues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960088/lucene-fields-vs-docvalues#28962537)

Comment: Thanks for providing the links. Was able to populate FieldValuecache by using Facet.version=2 parameter.